# Four mathematical notations for fraction $1/999$ and how to show/present they are equal

Tags: notation, fractions

I need some help for notation. I need to present fractions in four different format and I'd like to get it right. I just take $1/999$ for example, but of course it could be any fraction with positive integer denominator. So far my notation looks like this, leaving few parts undecided and unclear:

a)

$$1/999 = 0.001001001... = 0.\overline{001}$$

b)

$$.001 + .000001 + .000000001 + ...$$

How do you denote sequence like this up to infinity?

c)

$$1*10^{-(3*(n+0))} + 1*10^{-(3*(n+1))} + 1*10^{-(3*(n+2))} + ...$$

Again I don't know how to denote continuity and increment of the power $3n$.

d)

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1} - p)^{k-1}}{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1})^k}$$

where $p = 999$

Summation part is pretty much ok, except i don't know how to incorporate p = 999 part on it and ow to tie everything together.

After all, my purpose is to show that $a = b = c = d$ which context is why I prefer to ask them on one question rather than all on different questions.

Comment: You mean `0.\overline{001}` in the (a) part?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wish there was an easy reading and searchable guide for notation. But now I can read from source.

Comment: Something like [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Find the limit to show that all four limits are the same number.

Comment: @Syuizen can you show me, what do you mean with finding limits for parts a,b,c,d?

Comment: Now that I've looked at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365506/doubling-sequences-of-the-cyclic-decimal-parts-of-the-fraction-numbers I think it might be helpful to put a link to that question in this question, to show why d) is so interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $1/999 = 0.001001001\ldots = 0.\overline{001}$

Either of these is fairly standard notation. The overline 
format $0.\overline{001}$ is a little more explicit, 
so I think it would be preferred.

b) $.001 + .000001 + .000000001 + \cdots$

This denotes an infinite sequence in the way that
$1, 2, 3, \ldots$ indicates an infinite sequence: 
a little informally, but I think it is recognizable as a
mathematical notation.

The main problem with this one is it is hard to count the zeros.
One way to help see how big each number is is to consider a power of
$0.001$, like this:

$$0.001^1 + 0.001^2 + 0.001^3 + \cdots.$$

Using the $\sum$ summation notation, this is

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 0.001^k.$$

Alternatively, you could write this as

$$10^{-3} + 10^{-6} + 10^{-9} + \cdots$$

but now it is starting to look like

c) $1 \cdot 10^{-(3 \cdot (n+0))} + 1 \cdot 10^{-(3 \cdot (n+1))}
    + 1 \cdot 10^{-(3 \cdot (n+2))} + \cdots$

But there's a problem here: what is $n$? If you set $n=1$ then this evaluates
to  $10^{-3 \cdot 1} + 10^{-3 \cdot 2} + 10^{-3 \cdot 3} + \cdots$
which is OK. If you set $n$ to any other value then the sum will
*not* add up to $1/999$.

In $\sum$ notation, this series is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 10^{-3 \cdot (n + k)}$$

and we can rewrite it as follows:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 10^{-3 \cdot (n + k)}
 = 10^{-3n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( 10^{-3} \right)^k
 = 10^{-3n} \left( 1 + 0.001 + 0.000001 + \cdots \right).
$$

d) $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1} - p)^{k-1}}{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1})^k}$

This looks really complicated, but
let's try setting $N = 10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1}$.
Then

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1} - p)^{k-1}}{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1})^k} 
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(N - p)^{k-1}}{N^k} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(N - p)^k}{N^{k+1}} \\
& = \frac 1N \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac pN\right)^k \\
\end{align}

The sum in this last equation is a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) $\sum r^k$
with ratio $r = \left(1 - \frac pN\right)$.
The limit of such a series starting from the $k=0$ term
is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$.
Applying this result, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac pN\right)^k
= \frac{1}{1 - \left(1 - \frac pN\right)}$$

and therefore

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1} - p)^{k-1}}{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(p)\rfloor+1})^k} 
& = \frac 1N \left(\frac{1}{1 - \left(1 - \frac pN\right)}\right) \\
& = \frac 1N \left(\frac Np\right) \\
& = \frac 1p.
\end{align}

So it turns out it doesn't make much difference what $N$ is.

**Edit:** the rest of this answer has been revised to reflect upon
the related question, [Doubling sequences of the cyclic decimal parts of the fraction numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365506/doubling-sequences-of-the-cyclic-decimal-parts-of-the-fraction-numbers).

Now, it turns out that in the case where $p = 999$,
the series in part d) is term-for-term the same as the series in part b),
because $10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(999)\rfloor+1} - 999 = 1$.
The sum then comes down to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}
     \frac{1^{k-1}}{(10^{\lfloor\strut\log_{10}(999)\rfloor+1})^k}
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1000^k}
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 0.001^k$$

which is a more explicit way of writing the series
$0.001^1 + 0.001^2 + 0.001^3 + \cdots$.

But as the calculations above showed,
the formula for part d) works even when $p$ is not all $9$s
(that is, even when $p \neq 16^n - 1$ for any integer $n$).
For example, take $p = 98$.
The formula then says

$$\frac{1}{98}
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(100 - 98)^{k - 1}}{100^k}
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k-1}}{100^k}
 = 0.01 + 0.0002 + 0.000004 + 0.00000008 + \cdots$$

which well illustrates the "powers of $2$" pattern within the
repeating $42$-digit sequence in

$$\frac{1}{98} = 0.0\overline{102040816326530612244897959183673469387755}.$$

More could be said along these lines, but the question
[Doubling sequences of the cyclic decimal parts of the fraction numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365506/doubling-sequences-of-the-cyclic-decimal-parts-of-the-fraction-numbers)
is a better context for that.

Comment: Do you have time for a little chat about your answer? I remember on some SE site it was possible to have a conversation screen, but I can't see it here...

Comment: hope you have time to read and comment at least the last part of this: https://stackedit.io/viewer#!provider=gist&gistId=2eec41d340c0c0970c86&filename=Decimal+expansion+and+notation

Comment: @MarkokraM  There's a "chat" button at the bottom of this Web page that enables creating a new room. I did this for http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26191/decimal-notations-for-fractions. (The stackedit link did not seem to work for me.)

Comment: I will add it. Is it possible to show by which principle you get sigma sign out of the equation on part d?

Comment: I have changed how this answer ends, now that I know what the reason for part d) is. I think this is about as much as we need to say about the _notational_ question. Of course there is a lot more to say about the "doubling sequences" question that inspired this one, and I will try to post some kind of answer to that question too. (It may just take a little while longer to do that.)

Comment: Brilliant, that is more than enough for OP. I'm looking forward answer for other wider "doubling sequences" topic. At first I didn't want to mix it with the current one, but true, that is what I'm after.