# Is there a formula for the reverse sequence of a repetend?

Tags: decimal-expansion

@DavidK Did you ever expand on the reverse sequence/ backward sequence from this thread? [Doubling sequences of the cyclic decimal parts of the fraction numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365506/doubling-sequences-of-the-cyclic-decimal-parts-of-the-fraction-numbers)

"I'll give some thought to what can be said about that in not too many words."
The right to left order of repetends is something I have been researching. Thanks.

Comment: right to left? but that's finite

Comment: For example 1/95 can be expressed as "1/95 = 1/(100 - 5) = (1/100)/(1 - 5/100) =(1/100)[1 + 5/100 + (5/100)^2 + (5/100)^3 + ...] =01 + .0005 + .000025 + .00000125 + ..." showing the geometric series from left to right. The same repetend can be seen from right to left when observing powers of two: "\sum_{k=0}^n  {20^k} = {{20^{k+1} -1} \over {19}}"